# How to use dnsdock within docker-compose ?

Tags: dns, docker-compose

I was trying to use dnsdock to link containers inside docker-compose environment.

```
dnsdock:
    image: tonistiigi/dnsdock
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock
    ports:
        - 172.17.42.1:53:53/udp

pinger1:
  image: gliderlabs/alpine
  command: ping pinger2.pinger2.docker
  dns: 172.17.42.1
  environment:
   - DNSDOCK_NAME=pinger1
   - DNSDOCK_IMAGE=pinger1

pinger2:
  image: gliderlabs/alpine
  command: ping pinger1.pinger1.docker
  dns: 172.17.42.1
  environment:
   - DNSDOCK_NAME=pinger2
   - DNSDOCK_IMAGE=pinger2
```

And got the next issue during starting up:

`ERROR: Cannot start container 7cebbcde6c7ae85faaefd655aeb18a53710588c930888e15bdeb3c7392bda027: failed to create endpoint docker_dnsdock_1 on network bridge: Error starting userland proxy: listen udp 172.17.42.1:53: bind: cannot assign requested address`

Running with simple command:
`sudo docker-compose -f dnsdock-test.yml up`

Maybe someone knows what is the problem with config ?

Comment: Where did you get `172.17.42.1` from?  It might be easier to use `net: host` for the `dnsdock` container, and then use `127.0.0.1` for the `dns`  fields on the  services. This assumes you aren't already running another DNS server on the host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me after replacing ip with 172.17.0.1 instead of 172.17.42.1